# Three phase transformer output when using fewer than three phases as input?

Tags: transformer

For a three phase transformer in a rectified configuration where all the outputs are used to power a single output, what is the output voltage if one of the input phases is not connected at all? In specific for a standard dual Zigzag-Star(x2) configuration with the following secondary connections, will it work?

[image]

Comment: Looks like a 12-pulse rectifier. Have you tried to simulate it?

Comment: Be also aware that some three phase transformers may core-saturate with only two phases active but, as winny says, perform a simulation and answer this question yourself then come back with any queries about the results.

Comment: @Andyaka Not sure I have enough details for a Spice model, I will try. But if you had to guess, is this a configuration that core-saturates?

Comment: If the transformer has a common centre-core that is undersized then possibly. Normally, a common-centre core has all the balanced fluxes cancelling out and can be made significantly of less cross sectional area but, I'm only going on theory and not practice.